# Special non-www to www redirection under Amazon Elastic Load Balancer

Tags: redirect, iis-7, amazon-web-services

How to create a 301 redirect in IIS7 using the Rewrite Rule extension for IIS (writes to web.config) that will allow redirecting non-www to www - BUT, I don't want to use (.*), I want the URL rewriter to ignore URLs like DNS ones, so it can work under Amazon Load Balancer. Without it, Amazon Load Balancer will not be able to read the health check file, because it will be redirected and instead of getting 200OK it will get 301.

So I actually need a rule that will match a URL that contains mydomain.com, or one that start with it of course, so it won't loop.

The current rule is not good:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1">
       <match url="(.*)" />
         <conditions>
           <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.mydomain\.com$" negate="true" />
         </conditions>
         <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mydomain.com/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
 </rules>
</rewrite>
```

This will redirect URLs like dns.amzn.com to www.mydomain.com - I've tried it on IIS7.

Need a better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you come with a solution..

i added a condition using {HTTP_USER_AGENT} to not match ELB (user agent).
This stopped the rule from running for ELB, but i'm just testing this at the moment.

cheers

Added This Also:

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
<add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="ELB-HealthChecker" negate="true" />
<add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="HTTPS" negate="true" />                        
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

The bit you want is

```
<add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="ELB-HealthChecker" negate="true" />
```